# Error when boot: Could not write bytes: broken pipe

Tags: boot, nvidia, restore, pipe

Good day,

I see there are various questions about the same topic but it looks like the cause are somewhat different.  I tried tor resolve my problem by looking and trying some of the solutions but without any success so far.  I suspect my problems come in with the graphics drivers as I made a change to the resolution and then for some reason I could not reset the resolution to the original values.  I therefore installed the latest nvidia drivers by using the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but I think I made a mistake by then also installing this afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I rebooted and now I get this error:

```
Could not write bytes: broken pipe
```

Assistance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Does this Forum Post Help?

[Error: could not write bytes: Broken pipe](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058521)

In case you cant see it:

1. CTRL-ALT-F1 (to get a CLI)
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
4. sudo apt-get install invida-current-updates

and just in case:

*sudo rm .Xauthority*

Comment: No, I have done all these steps but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error message (in 12.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T500) immediately during the boot process and could not get through to any login screen. I had caused this behaviour before by manually modifying the xorg.conf file with a line that should do something desired. (Silly me! :-()

To reverse the entry I booted from another partition, mounted my dysfunct old root partition and changed the xorg.conf back again.

After that my familiar root partition returned like a charm.  :-)

Cheers,
Petra